# Cloud file storage using individual Google Accounts?

Tags: java, cloud, google-docs, google-account

I've never done any real web-related development, so I'm hoping for some guidance. I'm developing an application whose service generates and works with a single file. Currently that file is managed locally on the same machine as the application. For learning reasons, I would like for that file to be backed up and accessible in the cloud, so in the future I could, for example, write an Android application which can access the same file.

I don't want to host every user's file myself, because that seems like unnecessary work. Instead what seems to be the most practical approach would be to have the users authenticate using their Google Account and access/modify/store the file using their own Google Account. After doing research, the closest thing I have found would be using the Google Documents List API. But I don't necessarily want access to **all** of their documents. Since this is new to me, I'm hoping for just some guidance in the right direction.